# SAGA GIS Object based Image Analysis

Tags: saga, background

I'm performing OBIA On SAGA 7.1, the segments image has white background that will not allow me to view raster image beneath for supervised classification. The issue remain even when I set background color to transparent.
Any help pls.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks. I mean, in the process of objects based image analysis,  I have produced shape image containing polygons. When I superimposed this vector image on composite one, I will not be able to look through the poligons even if I set the transparency to be 100%. Once it is not transparent, the sampling training can not be possible. Thanks